# Writing a Path Coverage Tool

Tags: testing, code-coverage, multivalue

Currently, one of our production systems is handled by over 3000 programs written between 1986 and now . The code base is written in a non-standard language, which unfortunately lacks modern testing tools.

In a bid to improve our code quality moving forward I have been working to incorporate processes and build tools that will improve development and testing. I have just completely a line coverage tool so that we can help identify dead code + untested code during development.

Now, I would like to start work on adding Path Coverage to the tool.

**How should I go about this?**

Given that:

1) The line coverage tool acts as a pre-processor that injects code
2) I already have the ability to gather stats I set in said code.

**What data should I be recording as the program executes, and how do I interpret it?**

**How can I represent the results via HTML?**

I have already read the question [How to get started “writing” a code coverage tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092/how-to-get-started-writing-a-code-coverage-tool), which was about Java, however it didn't help (including the paper "Branch Coverage for Arbitrary Languages Made Easy").

Thanks in advance for any guidance given!

Comment: Have you seen the book, "Working effectively with legacy code" yet?

Comment: I'm curious why you want path coverage.  I've worked on avionics certified to the FAA's satisfaction (DO-178b level B and C only, never level A), and we only did statement coverage.  IMO gathering statement coverage had a low benefit, if you're already committed to high-quality unit tests (ie: a good engineer will write good tests (even without a coverage tool), a bad engineer won't (even when the coverage tool tells them their testing is deficient)).  There are of course times when the coverage tool prompts you to write a test you didn't know you needed to write, but that seemed rare.

Comment: @Robert. Not until now. @keysersoze. Statement coverage alone does not come close to cutting it. We have had many examples of code failure in production due to specific, untested combination of conditions. Also, the nature of the current code base precludes automated unit-testing. Path testing would act not only as a tool to discover things we have not thought of testing, but also a verification that the manual tests have actually been performed. Did I mention that it is legecy code with almost no documentation, included what we should be testing?

Comment: MC/DC testing can cover combinations of conditions within each conditional.  That would be an intermediate step between branch coverage and path coverage.   And the "Branch Coverage for Arbitrary Languages" paper applies directly in the MC/DC case, even if it isn't immediately obvious, as that paper is agnostic about the point-wise instrumentation inserted.

Comment: Um, when you say "multivalue" do you mean Pick-based software (DataBasic and its variants)?  If so, you might consider contacting me offline (see my SO icon for contact data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do path coverage, you need to get at the program control flow somehow.  An obvious method is to construct a real control flow graph, and then traverse segments of it to pick out "path fragments" (e.g., basis paths) to be used in your path coverage analysis.
(You can attempt to do this by string hacking the source code, but you'll likely fail;
parsing and flow analysis is too complex).

See [What's the point of basis path coverage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703570/whats-the-point-of-basis-path-coverage)
for a good stackoverflow discussion on basis paths.

To implement the required path coverage tool, you likely need to really parse the full legacy language completely.  For 3000 programs and a strong requirement for testing, using a industrial strength parser and infrastructure to do this would make sense.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) can be used to construct not only the parser, but the control flow analysis *and* the instrumentation required to collect path coverage data.  (The "Branch Coverage for Arbitrary Languages" made this point if all you wanted to do was collect branch coverage data, but there's more to DMS than just parsing).
DMS also has support for constucting control (and data flow) graphs if you need them,
as you apparantly do in this case; see [DMS constructed control flow graphs](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/FlowAnalysis.html).

DMS has been used to build control and data flow analyzers for C, Java and COBOL,
and has been used to build parsers for some 30+ langauges.  It can handle your legacy language if you are serious about this.

EDIT 10/31/2011:  DMS can now compute control flow for C++, so it would be a great foundation for a C++ path coverage tool.

Answer (score 3):

Path coverage measurement is a tricky subject.  First you have to define what you mean by a path in the first place.  Is a loop executed three times a different path than a loop executed four times?  If so, you have an infinite number of paths.  If not, there are test cases missed even if all paths are covered.

It might be that the better next step is branch coverage: measuring whether every conditional is executed both true and false.  This can be accomplished by recording sequences of line numbers.